# Yii2 DetailView: value of attribute using a function

Tags: php, yii2

I get an error when I use a function to get the value of an attribute and it's working normally using Gridview. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'label'  => 'subject_type',
            'value'  => function ($data) {
                return Lookup::item("SubjectType", $data->subject_type);
            },
            'filter' => Lookup::items('SubjectType'),
        ],
        'id',
        'subject_nature',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: From version 2.0.11 `value` may be also a function. See the ['docs'](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$attributes-detail).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fabrizio Caldarelli, on 05 January 2015 - 03:53 PM, said:
Yes because 'value' attribute is a real value or attribute name, as doc says

So your code should be:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'label'  => 'subject_type',
            'value'  => Lookup::item("SubjectType", $model->subject_type),
            'filter' => Lookup::items('SubjectType'),
        ],
        'id',
        'subject_nature',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 15):

I have experienced this kind of problem. The error was

`PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

what I did was transfer the function in the model like this.

```
function functionName($data) {
     return Lookup::item("SubjectType", $data->subject_type);
},
```

and then in your view.php file..

```
  [
            'label'=>'subject_type',
            'value'=>$model->functionName($data),
  ],
```

Answer (score 15):

Just use **call_user_func()**

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'label'  => 'subject_type',
            'value'  => call_user_func(function ($data) {
                return Lookup::item("SubjectType", $data->subject_type);
            }, $model),
            'filter' => Lookup::items('SubjectType'),
        ],
        'id',
        'subject_nature',
    ],
]) ?>
```